# How to access browser audio stream (Sound coming from the browser). Is there an API for this?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to record the audio coming from the browser. I have a recording extension and the requirement is that when the user is using headphones/earphones i need to be able to capture the stream coming from the browser,if the user in on a zoom/hangout call or even an youtube video.
I will then combine these streams later. But i am stuck trying to access the audio from the browser. Is there any way to achieve this?
Any suggestions/input appreciated.

Comment: Use [web audio](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio)?

Comment: When the user is using earphones/headphones the streams coming from the browser is not available in any media-devices(of kind:audio-input).